# Facebook Login Button Retrieving Wrong User Email Sometimes

Tags: facebook, button, authentication

I have a social network called Recommendation Book and I am using Facebook and Google Plus Login buttons to register users the first time they click the button and log them the second time they click the button. The other day I was talking to a girl and showing her my website and I tried to register her on my website using the facebook login button and the system logged her in another user's account, instead of registering her. Now I am almost sure it was a bug from facebook that made the facebook system return the email from another person and I was wondering if that an issue at all of facebook login button log users in the wrong account. So I am pasting the exactly code, the mobile version, and I wanna ask if there is anything wrong on this code, that is working, that could make the facebook system return another user's email from the user who tried to login? Is that an issue at all facebook login button logging users in the wrong account?

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--

$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".SpinnerTR").hide();

});

function myTrim(x) {
 return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
}

function setCookiesRB(id) {
 var date = new Date();
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

 var url = "http://localhost:8989/Login.jsp";

 if(url.toLowerCase().indexOf("localhost:8989") >= 0) {
  document.cookie = "IsRecommenderLogged=Yes; expires="+date.toGMTString()+"";
  document.cookie = "RecommenderId="+id+"; expires="+date.toGMTString()+"";
 } else {
  document.cookie = "IsRecommenderLogged=Yes; expires="+date.toGMTString()+"; domain=recommendationbook.com;path=/";
  document.cookie = "RecommenderId="+id+"; expires="+date.toGMTString()+"; domain=recommendationbook.com;path=/";
 }
}

/*
 *
 * Facebook Login
 *
 */

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
 if(response.status === 'connected') {
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".GoogleFacebookButtons").hide();
   $(".SpinnerTR").show();
  });
  register();
 } else if(response.status === 'not_authorized') {
  
 } else {
  // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if they are logged into this app or not.
 }
}

function checkLoginState() {

 FB.login( function(response) {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
   statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
 }, { scope: 'public_profile,email,user_birthday' } );

}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
  appId : '1054429214574465',
  cookie : true,
  xfbml : true,
  version : 'v2.2'
 });

 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  // statusChangeCallback(response);
 });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function register() {
 FB.api('/me', function(response) {

  var name = "";
  var email = "";
  var gender = "";
  var locale = "";
  var birthday = "";

  if(typeof response.name != "undefined") {
   name = ""+response.name+"";
  }

  if(typeof response.email != "undefined") {
   email = ""+response.email+"";
  }

  if(typeof response.gender != "undefined") {
   gender = ""+response.gender+"";
  }

  if(typeof response.birthday != "undefined") {
   birthday = ""+response.birthday+"";
  }

  if(typeof response.locale != "undefined") {
   locale = ""+ response.locale+"";
  }

  var posting = $.post("LoginFacebook.jsp", {name: name, email: email, gender: gender, locale: locale, birthday: birthday});

  posting.done(function(data) {

   setCookiesRB(""+myTrim(data)+"");

   window.location.href = "http://recommendationbook.com/Recommender.jsp?id="+myTrim(data)+"";
  });
 });
}

//-->
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">

<head>
 
<title>Recommendation Book</title>
 
<meta name="keywords" content="Recommendation Book Login" />
<meta name="description" content="Recommendation Book Login Page" />

<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

<body>

<div class="Geral">

 <div class="Corpo">

  <form method="post" id="Login" action="DoLogin.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
    <tbody>

    <tr class="GoogleFacebookButtons"><td class="tdLeft">
     <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
     Facebook Login and Registration<br />
     <a href="#" onclick="checkLoginState();"><img src="./img/static/FacebookButtonBig.PNG" border="0" alt=""></a>
     </div>
    </td></tr>

    <tr class="SpinnerTR"><td>Wait... <div id="Spinner" class="Spinner" style="display: inline;"><img width="200" height="200" src="./img/static/ajax-loader-GoldenRod.gif" alt="" /></div></td></tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>

 </div>

</div>

</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: Facebook doesn’t just return data of random users. Pretty sure that the error was on your end here – like someone else was logged into Facebook before on that same device/browser, and they did not log out properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It was on my side. What happens is that I thought that facebook would always return an email if the user succeed the login. But the user who is logging through the facebook login button can deny permission and then the facebook system will return junk or a generic facebook email. One of my users registered and as I wasn't checking I placed the junk facebook returned in the place of the email and I didn't notice. Later when I tried to register the girl I was mentioning the facebook system returned the same junk and that's why she was logged in the account of another girl. To fix I placed the following condition in the javascript:

```js
var emailRegex = new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)@([a-z0-9_.-]+)$");

if(!emailRegex.test(email) || email.toLowerCase().indexOf("facebook.com") >= 0) { }
```